# FRENCH COLOMBARD Won’t start fermenting

Tags: fermentation

I picked up 6 gallons each of Cabernet Sauvignon and FRENCH COLOMBARD from a local vendor here in Providence,RI. I used red star dry yeast, the cab started fermenting almost immediately but it’s been almost 24hrs and the Colombard isn’t moving yet. Should I be worried? I am making Brandy with both vessels BTW.

Comment: Did they put sulfites on the juice? Where was this juice coming from?

Comment: I wouldn't wait more than 24 additionnal hours.  I would oxygenate and add new yeast...

Comment: Thanks for the contributions, the Colombard finally started to ferment!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your question, poses a number of other questions to get you good information.
Give it a couple of days, it may take a bit to get going, which is not unusual.
Which Red Star did you use? Sprinkle or make a starter?  If appropriate for your wine, was it fresh yeast.
Temperature of your must and environment within recommended range for your yeast?
If the answer to these question are within the parameters for your wine and it doesn’t take off I would add some yeast nutrient (used on all my wines), and use a EC1118 yeast. If it doesn’t ferment with that yeast, somethings seriously wrong with your must, as it can almost wake the dead.